# If I make MongoDB my root factory, do I also need to register it with Configurator?

Tags: python, mongodb, pyramid

I'm trying to setup Pyramid's Authorization/Authentication feauture using my MongoDB as the root factory. I'm wondering if including these lines (config is Configurator)

```
db_url = urlparse(eval(settings['mongo_uri']))
conn = pymongo.Connection(host=db_url.hostname,
                          port=db_url.port)
config.registry.settings['db_conn'] = conn
config.add_subscriber(add_mongo_db, NewRequest)
```

is redundant? Is this necessary if I've already given config a mongo root factory?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend doing it that way. I wrote a pyramid addon to make things easier and cleaner.

Documentation here:

http://packages.python.org/pyramid_mongo/

The following is from a project I'm writing at the moment.

In my ini file (while it may be written in python settings)

```
mongo.uri = mongodb://localhost/
mongo.db = wife
```

In my configurator:

```
config.include('pyramid_mongo')
```

And in my root_factory:

```
from pyramid_mongo import get_db

...
...

def root_factory(request):
    db = get_db(request)
    return Root(db)
```

`get_db` can be called from anywhere, you have to pass a request as first argument. You can pass an other argument to query a different database.

Subscribers aren't needed in that case.

Btw, don't worry if it's written in the documentation that it might be risky, the current version of the package has 100% coverage and pass all tests. In the future, this package may integrate some tools in order to simplify traversal with mongodb.